# Why based on these, the partition problem cannot be concluded that P = NP?

Tags: algorithm, analysis, partition

I have learned that the Partition problem is included in the NP-Hard problem. I have done some searching about this Problem and seem to not find the reason why is for a certain problem it cannot be concluded that P = NP for a certain algorithm.

If Partition problem can be solved in time  () where  is the number of elements in the set, and  is the sum of the absolute values of the elements in the set. Why based on these, it cannot be concluded that P = NP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of P and NP states that an algorithm (non-deterministic in case of NP) exists that runs in a polynomial time. The trick is that the argument of the polynomial is the *size* of the problem, which is defined as the number of bits that encode the problem instance.

The trick with the Partition problem is that numbers are exponential in terms of bits encoding them, so () is actually exponential in terms of the size of the encoding.

The class of NP-complete problems where a deterministic polynomial time algorithm exists where the argument of the polynomial is the sum of *numbers* that define the problem is called **weakly** NP-complete. Partition, backpack and similar are in this class.

Related Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_NP-completeness

Comment: what do you mean by the size of the encoding? I have seen the pseudocode, by "bits that encode the problem instance" did you mean the sum of the elements in this partition problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because M is the sum of the absolute values of the elements. It's not polynomial to n, and thus it is not a polynomial time algorithm. Same idea with the dynamic programming solution for the knapsack problem.

Comment: why does the sum of absolute values of the elements causing it to become exponential?